# what exactly is this script doing? trying to understand javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
                var limitNum = 100;    
                var message = 'You are not able to type more than ' + limitNum + ' symbols!';    

                function checkLength(validator, args)    
                {    
                    var editor = <%=editortextbox1.ClientID%>;     // get a reference to RadEditor
                    var editorText = editor.GetText(true);     //get the HTML content of the control
                    args.IsValid = editorText.length > limitNum && editorText.length < 15;    
                }    
            </script>
```

is this script checking if editortextbox1 is empty or not ? if not, what is it doing? Also, if I do want to check that editortextbox1 is empty or not, how should I modify this script. Oh and what if I want this script to run for ALL the Textboxes on my page, what change do i need to make then?? Like I have 2-3 Text boxes(which are actually RadEditors). I want to check for null values in all the editors. How should I modify this script??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ensuring that the `editortextbox1` field has **less than** 15 characters, and **more then** than 100...meaning it can never be valid.  It seems like it *should* be:

```
args.IsValid = editorText.length <= limitNum && editorText.length >= 15;
```

to be a valid check.

Answer (score 1):

The script defines two variables and a function. It does not check anything.

When the function is executed, it sets `args.IsValid` to `false`. This is because `editorText.length > 100 && editorText.length < 15` is always `false`.

Answer (score 1):

currently args.IsValid will be always false:

```
editorText.length > limitNum && editorText.length < 15;
```

nothing can be greater than 100 and less than 15.
Anyway i believe that this function was currently meant to return the validity of the length of certain Textbox (probably to check a minimum and maximum length), anyways the script itself doesn't do anything, but the code that calls this function does.